# Access - Merga data from multiple columns into one either by Union or by Append Query

Tags: ms-access, append, union

Looking to merge multiple columns into one.  I'd like to go from this table:

```
> ID    |  Product 1 | Product 2 |  Product 3
> 1     |  Test 12   | Test23   |  Test 34
> 2     |  Test 11   | Test 22   |  Test 1212
```

To

```
**  ID   |  Product  **
    1    |  Test 12
    1    |  Test 23
    1    |  Test 34
    2    |  Test 11
    2    |  Test 22
    2    |  Test 1212
```

I've tried a Union query but can't get ID in there.  Will only join the 3 columns.

```sql
SELECT [Product 1] FROM [Table1]
Union All
Select [Product 2]  FROM [Table1]
UNION ALL 
Select [Product 3] FROM [Table1];
```

I've also tried append but it needs to be done one column at a time or I get "Duplicate output destination"

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: *but can't get ID in there* ... why not?

Answer (score 1):

Just include the ID in your union query:

```
SELECT ID, [Product 1] FROM [Table1]
UNION ALL 
SELECT ID, [Product 2] FROM [Table1] 
UNION ALL 
SELECT ID, [Product 3] FROM [Table1];
```

Comment: YES!  Thank you!!